# In vanilla JS, how can I add or remove a class from an element based on whether the scroll is at the top?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a sticky nav have a particular class when not scrolled at the top, and not have that class when scrolled at the top. Sorry if that's confusing.

What I'm stuck on right now is the fact that in the bottom piece of code `doc.scrollTop == 0` is evaluating to `true` whenever I scroll the mouse. What am I doing wrong?

```
     HTMLElement.prototype.removeClass = function(remove) {
        var newClassName = "";
        var i;
        var classes = this.className.split(" ");
        for(i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            if(classes[i] !== remove) {
                newClassName += classes[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        this.className = newClassName;
    }  

     window.onscroll = function() {

        var body = document.body; //IE 'quirks'
        var doc = document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
        doc = (doc.clientHeight) ? doc : body;

        if ( doc.scrollTop == 0 ) {
            document.getElementById('top').removeClass('scrolling');
            console.log("doc.scrollTop == 0");//TEST
        } else {
            document.getElementById('top').addClass('scrolling'); // need to make an addClass function ...
            console.log("doc.scrollTop != 0");//TEST
        }
    };
```

Comment: protip: what you call `removeClass` [already exists in vanilla JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), it's the `element.classList.remove(...)` function. Similary, `add` and `toggle` already exist (it might be a good idea to read up on modern HTML). Also, don't use the 15+ years old `window.onscroll`, use proper modern `window.addEventListener("scroll", function(evt) {...});` event handling. And finally, have a look at [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this to get the distance from the top:

```
var distance = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
```

And in your code:

```
 HTMLElement.prototype.removeClass = function(remove) {
    var newClassName = "";
    var i;
    var classes = this.className.split(" ");
    for(i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if(classes[i] !== remove) {
            newClassName += classes[i] + " ";
        }
    }
    this.className = newClassName;
}  

 window.onscroll = function() {

    var body = document.body; //IE 'quirks'
    var doc = document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
    doc = (doc.clientHeight) ? doc : body;

    var distance = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);

    if ( distance === 0 ) {
        document.getElementById('top').removeClass('scrolling');
        console.log("doc.scrollTop == 0");//TEST
    } else {
        document.getElementById('top').addClass('scrolling'); // need to make an addClass function ...
        console.log("doc.scrollTop != 0");//TEST
    }
};
```

Whilst this works, I would strongly suggest looking at improving your JS code to be in line with more modern practices.