# Two div together in parallel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing problem in maintaining two div parallel

First div should contain large data but scrolls with browser and 2 div should contain small data with stay fixed right hand side.

So when user scrolls page, both div should should stay in parllel

Like example is here(example)[https://app.thehomelike.com/apartment/RyeR9wQH4N7p2YRJA] 
in above page when you just visit after description, it shows two parllel div .. one stays fixed .. other move with browser scrollbar

Edit My efforts

```
             <div className="book">

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class className="page1">
                                    <h2>Page1</h2>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div className="page2" style={style} onScroll={this.handleScroll.bind(this)}>
                                    <h2>Page2</h2>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                    scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                //css

                .book table td {
                 vertical-align: top;
                }

              .page1 {
             border: solid 1px red;
             width: 400px;
           }

         .page2 {
         border: solid 1px red;
         width: 400px;
         position: static;
         }
```

Comment: you want grid view ??

Comment: I don't see any divs in parallel, just a pinterest waterfall image gallery

Comment: Yes grid view will be good

Comment: @mrid description section and available section  are parallel in given link.. go and look again

Comment: Trying to achieve the effect you want using a table is almost impossible. In the link that you supplied they used 2 divs, set to the browser height, float left, set widths and the first dive with an overflow_y set to scroll.

Comment: @jeff it will be good.. if you tell me doing some example

Comment: If you just want a fixed position it's `position:fixed;` in CSS.

Comment: @jeff  it is not possible by using some kind of fixed position??

Comment: I was just looking at your code. If you want block level Elements to be side by side use `float:left;`.

Comment: @PHPglue please go and check the link given by me.... and see how descripion and dates available section scrolling together...

Comment: It's actually basic CSS positioning. You should use 2 divs (not a table), with defined widths and then use position property.

Comment: Link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592058/make-two-parallel-div-colums-the-same-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(function(){
  $(document).scroll(function(){
   if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.largeCont').offset().top) {
    $(".fixedCont").addClass('active');
   } else {
    $(".fixedCont").removeClass("active");
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.section1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 300px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
section .largeCont {
  width: 70%;
}
section .fixedCont {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  width: 30%;
}
section .fixedCont.active {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section1">
  SOME CONTENT
</section>

<section>
  <div class="largeCont">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis enim maxime dicta quaerat id a maiores modi facilis, quisquam inventore at cum voluptas veniam obcaecati et sequi, libero, molestias tempore! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Officiis dolores vero, rem quod inventore, ipsam cupiditate rerum tempore explicabo veniam voluptatem dolorem minima dignissimos id est harum sequi odit, corporis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur consequuntur
    necessitatibus provident accusantium, explicabo velit dolorum molestiae soluta doloribus architecto ea nesciunt porro distinctio quod nulla mollitia, obcaecati impedit dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo eos, porro
    neque optio id aspernatur error atque blanditiis qui odio accusantium assumenda recusandae dolores culpa laborum voluptas, facere provident nam! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi a dignissimos similique, incidunt
    quas voluptatem fuga adipisci. Non deleniti obcaecati, doloribus tempora deserunt, facilis ipsum magnam quis veritatis ut nemo! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam quos adipisci debitis inventore sed, fugit, maxime vitae
    expedita consectetur a numquam nostrum repellendus vero mollitia, rem beatae vel ex aliquam!
  </div>
  <div class="fixedCont">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis mollitia amet ipsam vel saepe, rerum deserunt accusantium ratione reprehenderit eaque unde cumque! Expedita amet molestiae, dolorem porro nam nisi dolorum.
  </div>
</section>
```

Some like this? I think this is.

Comment: Yes you are right man...

Comment: Can you help me in core javascript.. because i am working in react.js so can't use Jquery

Comment: Is that  possible??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4zh7yuyq/2/

Sry the late, was working on it. Check the fiddle and let me now if it helps you

Comment: Yes its amazing.. let me try on my system now.. thanks lot

Comment: I should add that I took almost all from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166846/in-vanilla-js-how-can-i-add-or-remove-a-class-from-an-element-based-on-whether just to let you know.

Comment: But do you know any npm react library.. which can give me this kind of similiar feature in react

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll

I found this one, but to be honest I've never used before.

Comment: Have you ever worked with react.js... if you help me in implementing this... i can pay you.. is that possible from your side

Comment: Sry, but I'm affraid I've never worked with react.js. How are you working with it? Have you a test server or something? I could try to help, but don't be so sure.

Comment: I am working on webpack with react.js running on npn ....

Answer (score 2):

```
.book {
  position: relative;
}
.page1 {
  background-color: azure;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
}

.page2 {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ygo20xf/

Comment: Its amazing man... Thanks... I like it....

Comment: `overflow-y: scroll` to force the vertical scrollbar to appear

Comment: No problem. If you want to learn more about positioning https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: problem is that i some content above also.. so can't use this one...

Comment: Because its allways fixed left hand side.. so its not usefull

Answer (score 0):

```css
section {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    background: aqua;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
div#one {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
div#two {
    margin-left: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div id="one">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think you should check link again ...

Comment: Thanks updating ...  but this is not required please go and check the link given by me..

Comment: you wanted the apartment list and map layout side by side , right ?

Comment: You are quite near.. but i just want one scroll bar.. that will be browser scrollbar.. no scroll bar for div

Comment: Is that possible??

Comment: That's the div's scrollbar only. It just looks like the browser's scrollbar since the div's height is the same as browser's height. If you inspect the page you are talking about, you'll see they have also done the same thing ( `#map-list .gallery-container { height: 100%;  overflow-y: scroll; }` )

Comment: But i don't want scrollbar for div.. just want scrollbar with browser

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```css
.box {
    width:100px;
    display:box;
    /* Firefox */
    display:-moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
     /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    /* W3C */
    display:box;
    box-orient:horizontal;
}

.box .column1 {
    -moz-box-flex:1.0; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-flex:1.0; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -ms-flex:1.0; /* Internet Explorer 10 */
    box-flex:1.0;
    background: yellow;
}

.box .column2 {
    -moz-box-flex:1.0; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-flex:1.0; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -ms-flex:1.0; /* Internet Explorer 10 */
    box-flex:1.0;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
 <div class="box">
      <div class="column1">
          a<br>b
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
         a
      </div>
   </div>
```